# Should there ever be a dead short across where a capacitor goes in a circuit?

Tags: capacitor, repair, short-circuit

I have an old video card that is not working right and creating instabilities in the system it's plugged into. I measured several dead shorts across capacitors in circuit using my multimeter.

After removing two of the capacitors that read as shorter in circuit I found that the are not shorted and that the problem is elsewhere on the board. I can measure a dead short between the solder points with the capacitors removed.

There are still other capacitors to remove which are read as shorted but I have a burning question as a hobbyist.

Is there a use case for two vias meant to take a capacitor to *ever* read as shorted or is this always indicative of a fault?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you measure milliohms? or can you make current tracer?

Comment: I have a capacitance tester if that's what you're asking. These capacitors read as 1900uF despite being labeled as 1500uF. I don't know if that is a result of being in a faulty circuit for an extended period of time or if they came like this from the manufacturer. I actually have a separate question asked elsewhere on this very topic. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/587547/

Comment: I don't know anything about current tracing.

Comment: One example where this would be reasonably expected would be a parallel tank circuit.  However, I don't know of many examples where this would be implemented with a fairly large electrolytic capacitor (not that they don't exist, I just don't know everything).  What are you calling a "dead short?"  Does your ohmmeter read the same as when the probes are touching each other, or is there a discernable difference?

Comment: Diodes often fail dead short (other semis like MOSFETs can too). But without a schematic or a LOT of work ... it's dead, Jim.

Comment: Caps are likely -10% to +20% tolerance, so 1900/1500 = 26% over-spec.  Some ratings are -10% to +35%.

Comment: A dead short to me is even I can make two points between my multimeter probes beep when set in continuity mode. I removed all of the capacitors that read as shorted in circuit. They all test fine but the board itself still reads as a short between where the capacitors were.

Comment: Any (discharged) capacitor seems like a dead short when you first test its resistance, so don't be fooled. Is the video card working at all?  Last ditch #1 -- replace all electrolytics. Last ditch #2 -- Reflow the main video processor..   Look up Louis Rossman and watch his reflow instructionals.

Comment: It looks like you've got a regulator or two on board.  You should be able to look them up, and test them, even if you have to desolder them and use their datasheets and a resistor to make a test circuit.

Comment: I checked all of the regulators and only one tested short to ground. I lifted the voltage-in pin which removed the component from the short but it was not the offending part. I also lifted half a diode and desoldered all of the other shorted capacitors with no improvement. I can only measure a short between 5-9 ohms across various SMD capacitors and resistors and the resistance is smallest on the underside at one of the SMD components directly beneath the GPU. I think I've picked all of the low hanging fruit and suspect that the short may by inside the GPU die itself.

Comment: @Zhro Measuring 5-9 ohms on a chip pin might be normal. Especially if you don't know what the pin does and to which external components it connects to.

Comment: Reminder that some video cards can easily use hundreds of watts at 12 volts, which is less than 1 ohm. And if the capacitor is on a low voltage rail the resistance is even lower. Could be meant for a hundred amps at one volt. *This* video card looks too old and has too small of a heatsink to be using that much power.

Answer (score 2):

The continuity test beep mode will beep as long as the measured voltage is low enough.

You can't determine that there is a dead short or not in continuity beep mode.

The multimeter comes with a manual; read the manual to figure out what is the resistance range where it beeps and where it does not beep.

Any circuit with capacitors or semiconductors will easily beep in continuity test mode.

It definitely does not mean that there is a dead short.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a dead short across a filter capacitor. But... A great deal of capacitance looks just like a short until it charges-up. I can't think of an instance where it would be part of the design, so just make sure it's not the capacitor, or the capacitance of the circuit, fooling you.

Measure the actual resistance across the capacitor (in-circuit), instead of using the continuity tester, and see if the resistance increases with time -- if the resistance goes up, that was the capacitor looking like a short.  If the resistance is low and stays pretty low (<= an ohm or two), then it's a real short.

Comment: The continuity I'm measuring is across the two vias after the capacitor has been removed and is not momentary which I understand can be the case when tested in circuit. Is this still consistent with your answer?

Comment: Do you mean the holes the capacitors came out of?  Or vias downstream from there?  Once signals go underground by via, it's hard to tell what's going on.  Did you measure resistance? And did the resistance settle, or keep moving? Observe for at least 10-15 seconds.